# Constraints on parameter type

Tags: javascript

I have the following code :

```
class MotherClass {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class ChildClass extends MotherClass {
  constructor(name, age) {
    super(name);
    this.age = age;
  }
}

function myFunction(param1) {
   //do something
}
```

How can I check in myFunction that `param1` is a MotherClass (or an instance of a class that extends MotherClass) ?

Comment: `param1 instanceof MotherClass` should work, even if it's ChildClass which is passed to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [instanceof](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-instanceofoperator) operator

```
class MotherClass {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class ChildClass extends MotherClass {
  constructor(name, age) {
    super(name);
    this.age = age;
  }
}

function myFunction(param1) {
   //do something
   console.log(param1 instanceof MotherClass);
}

myFunction(new ChildClass("bla", "bla"));
```

Answer (score 1):

@iccthedral answer will fit your needs.

Also, just be careful of `instanceof` because he can sometimes produces result that will lead you astray.

Eric Elliot's talked about this a lot [there](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/common-misconceptions-about-inheritance-in-javascript-d5d9bab29b0a).

Here it's an example directly taken from the link above.

```
function foo() {};
var bar = { a: "a"};
foo.prototype = bar; // Object {a: "a"}
baz = Object.create(bar); // Object {a: "a"}
baz instanceof foo // true. oops.
```